# what should I do when there is nothing to do in office

Tags: work-environment

As stated in the title, what should I do when there is nothing to do in the office? Should I go ask my supervisor for any work or should I wait for them to come to me? I am a new hire to the company and my first job so I am not very familiar with what to do in the workplace yet.

Answer (score 2):

Show you have some initiative and aren't lazy and ask your supervisor if they have anything for you to do. If you regularly find you have nothing to do you risk getting the heave-ho.

Answer (score 0):

McDonalds has an old saying: "Leaning time is cleaning time!". But if you're not working for MD's then go to your supervisor. If they're too busy to find you something then go find some documentation you can read. Having nothing to do when you're new is standard in your first week. Then after a couple of months you'll miss these quiet times.