# Nothing to do @work

Tags: work-time

In my office the summer is usually very calm. I already did all I could do (tidying up, looking for optimisations, helping colleagues...). I also took some hours off... How do you deal with it?

Comment: Related https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/159205/is-it-appropriate-to-say-i-have-nothing-to-do-for-now-in-the-office

Comment: Quote from an older employer at one of my first jobs: "Work is a scarce resource that needs to be used up sparingly". ("Work" meaning "things that you can do"). That was after I did a supposedly 3 day job in two hours.

Comment: What kind of work do you do?

Answer (score 2):

You can go through some courses during office hours and learn something new in that time.